# concurrent.futures error when using imports from another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a piece of toy code which does some dummy work to test parallelization. The code works fine as it is, but it fails if I try to import a class from another file. It gives me the error `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

```py
#from Geometry import * <- this line causes the code to break
import concurrent.futures
import itertools
import random
import time

class ConProc:

    def dummy(self, param):
        time.sleep(random.random() * 3) # simulate a longer job
        return param[0] * param[1]

    def main(self):
        ht_iterator = range(4)
        wt_iterator = range(5)
        paramlist = list(itertools.product(ht_iterator, wt_iterator))

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            ret = executor.map(self.dummy, paramlist)

            for result in ret:
                print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp = ConProc()
    cp.main()
```

Contents of `Geometry.py`-

```py
import math
import numpy as np


class vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return



class ray(vector):
    pass

class sphere:

    def __init__(self, center, radius, material):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.material = material

    def intersects(self, ray, ray_direction):
          # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
          sphere_to_ray = ray - self.center
          b = np.dot(2*ray_direction, sphere_to_ray)
          c = np.dot(sphere_to_ray, sphere_to_ray) - self.radius*self.radius
          disc = b * b - 4 * c

          if disc >= 0:

              dist = (-b - math.sqrt(disc)) / 2
              if dist > 0:
                  return dist

          return None

    def normal(self, hit_pos):
        return (hit_pos - self.center) / np.linalg.norm(hit_pos - self.center)
```

I find this problem puzzling because this error occurs even if I don't actually use anything from Geometry.

Sometimes I also get this error `BrokenProcessPool: A child process terminated abruptly, the process pool is not usable anymore`

**Additional Info:**
Stack-trace -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\test_conc.py", line 42, in <module>
    test = cp.main()

  File "C:\Users\test_conc.py", line 35, in main
    for result in ret:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 476, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Comment: how are you running your code? I'm trying it on my machine (Mac, Python 3.7.5) and it's working fine.

Comment: i am using python 3.7.3 in Spyder IDE, Windows...this is strange.

Comment: Getting OSError: handle is closed on my end, on win10 python 3.8.3, regardless of Geometry.py import.

Comment: @PyWalker2797 - could you try running it outside of spider? Just run it with python3 my_script.py from the command line?

Comment: @Roy2012 It works through command line. What does this mean?

Comment: one last question - when you run it in Spider, do you run it in debug mode or as 'run without debug' (or whatever it's called in Spider)?

Comment: I just 'run' it, using f5? I guess that's without debug mode... not sure.

Comment: yep. It seems that F5 is just run. My suspicion is that Spider doesn't just run your code via Python, but wraps some of your code with additional code. It's that additional code that's causing the issue.